# what is the best way to check if a parameter is set in PHP within a jQuery template?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-templates

what is the best way to check a parameter is set in PHP within jQuery template?

I have this code:

```
var custID = '<?php echo htmlentities( $_GET['custID'] ); ?>';
```

I need to check that it is set, if it is set then echo that value, if it is not produce an error.

Comment: I don't know php, but in J2EE.. I always wrap it inside quotes to avoid `var custId = ;`. With quotes you would end up getting valid empty string instead of an error in case if the `custID` is not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd say:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['custID']))echo "var custID = '".$_GET['custID']."';";
 else echo "alert('error');";
?>
```

Comment: but if there is an error I want it to display the error on to the screen.

Comment: Yes that will work, but its a bit messy. is there an alternative, Im wondering whats the most common way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var custID = <?php echo htmlentities( isset($_GET['custID']) ? $_GET['custID'] : "" ); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like that, first we need to check if the custID exists :

```
<?php
    $custId = isset($_GET['custID'] && !empty($_GET['custId']) ? htmlentities($_GET['custId']) : false;
    if(!$custId) {
        //cutsId don't exists, show your error
?>
    Error
    <script type="text/javascript">var custId = false;</script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">var custId = '<?php echo $custId; ?>';</script>
<?php } ?>
```

There you're sure that the javascript var will not throw an error.

There's another way within the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var custId = '<?php echo isset($_GET['custId']) ? htmlentities($_GET['custId']) : false;?>';
</script>
```

Note that i'm keeping the quotes or they might be an error because `var custId = ;` is not valid but `var custId = '';` is.

If custId doesn't exists, the Javascript var will be empty (not undefined) and you could check it like that :

```
if(custId.length)
    //custId exists
```

Comment: Is that the best way of doing it?

Comment: If you keep the quotes before writing a small line it'll also do the trick, i'm updating.